# Internal monoidal categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, internal-categories, internalization

It is well known that the notion of an [internal category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+category) can be generalized to categories without pullbacks by considering cotensors of comodules in a monoidal category. I'm curious about the other direction, considering internal monoidal categories in a category with products.

> **Definition.** Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category with finite products. A **strict internal monoidal category** $\mathscr{C}$ in $\mathcal{C}$ consists of an internal category $\mathscr{C}$ in $\mathcal{C}$ together with internal functors $\otimes:\mathcal{C}\times\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{C}$, $I:{\bf 1}\to\mathscr{C}$ such that
> $$
> \otimes\circ(\otimes\times1)=\otimes\circ(1\times\otimes),
> $$
> $$
> \otimes\circ\langle1,I\circ!\rangle=1_\mathscr{C}=\otimes\circ\langle I\circ!,1\rangle.
> $$

We can internalize weak monoidal categories in a bicategory:

> **Definition.** Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a bicategory with products. An **internal monoidal category $\mathscr{C}$ in $\mathcal{C}$** consists of an internal category $\mathscr{C}$ in $\mathcal{C}$ together with internal functors $\otimes:\mathcal{C}\times\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{C}$, $I:{\bf 1}\to\mathscr{C}$ together with internal natural isomorphisms
> $$
> \alpha:\otimes\circ(\otimes\times1)\Rightarrow\otimes\circ(1\times\otimes),
> $$
> $$
> \iota^r:\otimes\circ\langle1,I\circ!\rangle\Rightarrow 1_\mathscr{C},
> $$
> $$
> \iota^\ell:\otimes\circ\langle I\circ!,1\rangle\Rightarrow 1_\mathscr{C},
> $$
> such that the following diagrams commute:
> [image]
> [image]
> (top is the pentagon identity, bottom is the triangle identity)

Have these notions been studied in the literature anywhere? We can consider an internal braiding in a bicategory by considering an internal natural isomorphism $B^\otimes:\otimes\Rightarrow\otimes\circ\pi_1\times\pi_0$ such that the following diagrams commute

[image]
[image]

The braiding is symmetric iff ${B^\otimes}^{-1}=B^\otimes_{\pi_1\times\pi_0}$, so on and so forth. I can't find mention of these notions after a few months of playing around with them but I'm certain they've been written down before, I'm just wondering if there's anything that's been made publicly available. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Bicategories internal to 2-categories have been studied in [Internal bicategories](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.4284) by Douglas–Henriques. Internal monoidal categories ought to be one-object internal bicategories.

Comment: @varkor Thanks for the pointer, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been done in [Section 1.3](https://www.repository.cam.ac.uk/bitstream/handle/1810/298234/thesis-final.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y#page=20) of Enrico Ghiorzi's PhD thesis:

> Ghiorzi, E. (2019). Internal enriched categories (Doctoral thesis). https://doi.org/10.17863/CAM.45286. [Link](https://www.repository.cam.ac.uk/handle/1810/298234).

It has also lead to these two preprints:

> Ghiorzi, E. (2020). Complete internal categories. [arXiv:2004.08741 [math.CT]](https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.08741).
>
> Ghiorzi, E. (2020). Internal enriched categories. [arXiv:2006.07997 [math.CT]](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.07997).

Comment: +1 because I was about to post Enrico's thesis